# When testing a flask app, how can I send a file and data in the request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

If I wanted to send a request to a flask app, how could I do something like:

```
test_client = Flask(__name__).test_client()
test_client.post('/media', data={'file': (open('file.jpg'), 'file.jpg')})
```

this works but when I try to add other arguments to `data` so **the request is sending more than just the file** I get an error back.

How can I pass arguments other than just the file?

When I send something like:

```
 test_client.post('/media', data={'file': (open('file.jpg'), 'file.jpg'), 'abc': '123'})
```

and when I print `request.json` on my endpoint, I get back `None`.

Comment: what error ? Always add full error message in question ?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, I just get None when I print request.json

Comment: do you run `Flask` in debug mode ? maybe it shows some information. Or add `print()` if `/media` function to see what's going on - maybe there is error.

Comment: it looks like it stores the variables in request.form instead of request.data, I can't figure out why though

Comment: I never tied it with `Flask` but module `requests` always send `data=` as `form` information (and it has no `data` information). maybe here it works the same.

Comment: flask doc: [json](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.json) To get JSON you have to send with `mimetype` as `application/json`